# how can I populate dropdown using GCP Deployment Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I have a deployment manifest which includes amongst others, a `zone` property. I want the user to be able to select the `zone` from a dropdown. I know it is possible to do this in AWS CloudFormation. Is there an equivalent method for GCP DM? There a number of properties for which such a selection would be useful.

When I launch a deployment from the Marketplace, these dropdowns are populated, so definitely it *is* possible.

Comment: Are you using `gcloud` or API?

Comment: This question is a bit unclear. Usually, when you click on the button "LAUNCH ON COMPUTE ENGINE" in the marketplace, it returns you to the new application configurations page, where you are able to select the "Zone" where the VM hosting the application will be deployed? If this is not what you are referring to, could you please provide more information?

Comment: I guess GCP Deployment Manager could be considered to be API based since eventually all of the resources are created via REST calls.

To be clear, I am not clicking on any buttons. I am trying to use the equivalent of AWS CloudFormation in GCP Deployment Manager (https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/).

Comment: For the benefits of community users, as detailed in this [article](https://medium.com/boltops/a-simple-introduction-to-aws-cloudformation-part-1-1694a41ae59d) "CloudFormation is a tool from AWS that allows you to spin up resources effortlessly. You define all the resources you want AWS to spin up in a blueprint document, click a button, and then AWS magically creates it all. " which seems similar to the Google [Cloud Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/deployment-manager-and-cloud-marketplace). Still didn't understand the exact issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the additional functionality provided by [Deployment Manager AutoGen](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-autogen) to generate a package that can be deployed on the GCP Marketplace (with additional API's) is only available to Google Technology Partners, and there is an approval process for that.